# What dependencies I need to run spark.read.csv("...") in local distribution?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is whole project: https://github.com/sryza/aas/blob/master/ch02-intro/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/datascience/intro/RunIntro.scala

and the dependencies don't exist. I have replaced paths "hdfs:////" to local paths and how can I run them?

For example how to run:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("Intro")
      .getOrCreate
spark.read.csv("C:/test.csv")
```

The error is crazy: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean scala.util.Properties$.coloredOutputEnabled()'`
Not able to google the solution.

My pom.xml file is:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

Comment: try to add `file:///` **`spark.read.csv("file:///C:/test.csv")`** for local distribution!

Comment: didn't help. Error is the same :(

Comment: You just need spark-sql and spark-core as dependencies.

Comment: you have not set master

Comment: Install the spark first

Comment: I have added my pom.xml dependencies. I have spark installed. What means "set master"?